# How to detect if a content in webview is Pannable?

Tags: android, webview

According to [google design guide](https://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/swipe-to-refresh.html#swipe-to-refresh-swipe-to-refresh) Swipe to refresh should not be used in

- Navigation drawers
- Home screen widgets
- Pannable content

How to detect that the current webpage in the webview has pannable content? For eg. `google maps`